# вывести на страницу все ключи массива которые содержат значение равное значению введенное в input

Tags: javascript

Функция должна вывести в out-9 все ключи массива a9, которые содержат значение, равное значению в input.i-9. Вывод через пробел. Если значений - нет - то выводить пустую строку.

let a9 = {
b: 17,
e: 22,
j: 17,
k: 22,
d: 54,
};

```
<div>Input i-9<input type="text" class="i-9"></div>
 <button class="b-9">Task-9</button>
 <div class="out-9"></div>
```

Написал такой код , но он не работает,подскажите пожалуйста где ошибка,заранее благодарен за помощь в решении.

```
let out9 = document.querySelector(".out-9");
let i9 = document.querySelector(".i-9");

     function f9(){
      let out = '';
      a9[i9.value] = i9.value;
      for (let key in a9){
         if (a9[key] == i9.value){
           out.textContent += key + ' ';
         } else {
           out.textContent += '';
         }
      }
      i9.value = '';
      out9.textContent = out;
    }
    document.querySelector(".b-9").onclick = f9;
```

Comment: Как вы думаете, что такое `out.textContent`?

Comment: А это зачем? `a9[i9.value] = i9.value;`

Comment: решая задачки запутался совсем,  понял свою ошибку, благодарю за подсказку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Т.к. `out` это просто переменная с типом строка, а не DOM элемент, то конкатенировать надо не так

```
out.textContent += ...
```

а просто

```
out += ...
```